# How to suppress "underfull \vbox" warning for one specific \marginpar

Tags: marginpar

I have just started using LaTeX, so forgive me if this is a basic question. I have a `\marginpar` in a two column article. It is very narrow (despite me increasing `\marginparwidth`). When the document is rendered I get the error message

```
Underfull \vbox (badness 1102) has occurred while \output is active
```

I understand why I am getting it and I am happy to live with it, as the output looks ok to me. I would like to suppress this warning message in relation to the specific `\marginpar` that I know is causing it, but without disabling the appearance of other potential error or warning messages.

Is this possible?

Comment: a marginpar is set in the main loop before the output routine is invoked. The box in this message is almost always either the main page (if you have flushbottom in effect) or the head or foot, as they are the three box set within the output routine. add `\showboxbreadth\maxdimen\showboxdepth\maxdimen` to your preamble and you get more info that should allow you to identify the box, either way if you could post with a complete small example that shows the problem it would help.

Comment: Hi, I know which box is causing the problem because removing the box removes the error. I know it is due to the amount of text in the box making it too long and narrow for (I guess) TeX's liking :) I hoped there was something I could wrap the box in to suppress the warning...

Answer (score 3):

```
\vbox (badness 1102
```

isn't very bad, LaTeX by default doesn't warn for badness under 1000 so you could just increase that to 1200 by adding

```
\vbadness=1200
```

this does not affect TeX's setting, just the warnings it gives.